# Error saving image odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo

I have created my own class named `notary.notary`. It contains field type 'Binary' named `image`.

When I save form the image doesn't display.

I don't get any error in traceback.

This is my code:

```
class notary_notary(models.Model):

_name = 'notary.notary'
image = fields.Binary("Image")
```

And my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <menuitem id="menu_notary" name="Gestion des notaires" />

        <record id="view_notary_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">notary.notary.form</field>
            <field name="model">notary.notary</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Notaires">
                <sheet>
                    <field name="image" widget='image' class="oe_left oe_avatar" options='{"preview_image": "image_medium", "size": [90, 90]}'/>*
```

Comment: Update your question with faced error/server trace-back.

Comment: i don't get any error but when i save my form the image doesn't display

Comment: Is your `notary_notary` class right? `_name` and `image` had to be indent right first.

Comment: it's work now i just remove the part "option=......" in file .xml